# Finder in Snow Leopard Does Not Show All Files in Directory

Tags: macos, file-management

I have 1189 mp3 files in a single directory (Finder says I have 1189 files and Terminal reports 1189 files). The terminal command: "ls -1" (el es space dash one) shows the long list of files; they have numeric/alpha names that always sorts properly.  The problem is in the Finder listing; When I scroll through this very large directory (regardless of display mode - list, column, or cover flow) there are gaps in the files displayed (remember they are sequential and finder SHOULD sort them the same as terminal)  Though my research it appears that the finder listing is limited to about 1024 entries. I don't know if this also applies to any previous OS X releases.  Is there a way to tell Finder to display more (all) files?

Answer (score 2):

Finder does *not* sort files the same as the terminal.

The terminal (or more correctly, ls), sorts using simple ASCII ordering. The Finder uses the Unicode Collation Algorithm - see [this Apple Support article](http://support.apple.com/kb/TA22935?viewlocale=en_US)

BTW, I managed to create a folder with > 100,000 files and Finder displayed all files.